# Passing a PHP variable into Javascript returns NULL

Tags: javascript, php, json

I know there are a lot of questions covering something similar, but I've tried the answers without any luck.

**Snippet of PHP:**

```
$usernum_query = "SELECT numPersonID FROM tbllogins WHERE txtUserName='$currentuser'";

if(!$usernumber = $db1->query($usernum_query)){
    die('There was an error running the usernumber query [' . $db1->error . ']');
}

while($row = $usernumber -> fetch_assoc()) {
  $userIDnum = $row['numPersonID'];
  $userIDnum = utf8_encode($userIDnum);
}
```

**Snippet of Javascript:**

```
$(function(){

  $("#0").click(function(){

        var userIDnum = <?php echo json_encode($userIDnum); ?>;
        alert(userIDnum);
```

The most common answer I've come across says to UTF_encode my variable, which I think I've done correctly. I've also tried:

```
var userIDnum = <?php echo $userIDnum; ?>;
```

Which doesn't work.

In my HTML outside of the script,

```
<?php echo json_encode($userIDnum); ?>
```

return "90" (with the quotes)

```
<?php echo $userIDnum; ?>
```

returns 90 (without the quotes).

Within the script, I get null and no alert box, respectively.

Any ideas as to why the variable isn't passed into the script? Thanks!

edit: tried with quotes and got the same result

Comment: Is this inside a .js file? If so, it's not parsed by PHP

Comment: Put double quotes around your php script --> "<?..?>";

Comment: If the problem was that the variable wasn't defined, it would alert "undefined". So, if you don't get any alert at all, then the click function isn't getting called, or you have a JS console error prohibiting further execution.  Have you stuck a breakpoint on the line and seen if it gets hit?

Comment: What does PHP print in the code? That is, what is <?php .. ?> replaced to?

Comment: Is the JS code inline or is it in an external File? View the source of your JS code in the browser (or its developer tools). If the JS is in an external file and still contains PHP, you need to rename the file to .php or change your server config to use PHP for that file. Also check if you see an error in your browser console.

Comment: your alert can break depending on what's coming in from json_decode and especially when you don't have double quotes around your js  var userIDnum = <?php echo json_encode($userIDnum); ?>; It looks like you have things setup correctly, whats not clear is that is this all in a .php file? you shouldn't get NULL in that case.

Comment: @bizco, whether PHP outputs 90 or "90", it's valid JS.  Your error is likely somewhere else.  E.g. your #0 selector.click might not be getting triggered, or you have a console error that you are not telling us about.  We need more info.  Grab the generated JS source from your page and stick it into a JSFiddle if you can so people can help you better.  There's not enough to go on without seeing the generated source or having an error message.

Comment: @adeneo: Yes, I'm referencing a jquery library. Judging by the answers and downvote, I'm assuming that's where my problem lies.

Comment: @calamari: the click is definitely being triggered, as I get an alert with "Null" as the message. I think my problem is what adeneo mentioned in his comment. My <script> is in <head> but I'm referenced a .js file.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert This seems to be the problem. I wondering if I can change the server config in the IIS Manager - I'll take a look. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can rename the file to `.js.php`. Just make sure you set the correct content type using `header('Content-Type: application/javascript');` at the top.

Comment: Ah, I thought when you were saying "In my HTML outside of the script" was that you were viewing the source and seeing 90 or "90" where it should be, and you wrote "no alert box".  If I can make a recommendation, put your value in a data-attribute in the HTML (e.g. `<body data-user-id="<?php echo $userId ?>">`.  This keeps you from mixing code languages together which is hard to read, and would allow your external script to run correctly without making it a PHP page.

Comment: @calamari Thanks for the follow up.

This worked perfectly in Chrome. I used `<div id="user" data-number="<?php echo $userIDnum ?>"></div>` in my HTML and 

`var userinfo = document.querySelector('#user');
   alert(userinfo.dataset.number);` 

in the script. Unfortunately, userinfo.dataset.number returns 'SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'number': object is null or undefined` in IE9, and the majority of users will be using IE9... :/ Any ideas?

Regardless, your solution worked - if you post it as an answer I can select it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Taken from comments as requested]**

If I can make a recommendation, put your value in a data-attribute in the HTML (e.g. `<body data-user-id="<?php echo $userId ?>">`. This keeps you from mixing code languages together which is hard to read, and would allow your external script to run correctly without making it a PHP page.

As far as IE9, I'll take a quick look.  You might want to see how jQuery manages the data attributes.  You should, at the least, have access to

```
domObject.getAttribute('data-user-id').
```

Yep, just did a quick lookup, and even IE10 doesn't support the dataset feature. So, you'll need to use getAttribute for IE <= 10.

Comment: Thanks, calamari. Your answer put me on the track to a solution. Much appreciated. I posted the code I used in a separate answer for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

A solution based on a suggestion by calamari:

In the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 11 ]> <html class="ie10orless"> <![endif]-->
<head>
... more code here ...
```

And in the script:
            var oldIE;
                if ($('html').is('.ie10orless')) {
                    oldIE = true;
                }

```
    if (oldIE) {
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].getAttribute("data-number"); 
        alert("in IE");
        alert(x);
    } else {
        var userinfo = document.querySelector('#user');
        alert("NOT in IE");
        alert(userinfo.dataset.number);
    }
```

Hope this helps someone else. Thanks everyone for the other suggestions as well.

Answer (score -1):

There are couple of things to check. Lets say this is your script:

```
<?php $htmlString= 'testing'; //Lets say this is a snippet of your php 
?>
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!-- And this is the snippet of your JS -->
      // notice the quotes around the ?php tag         
      var htmlString="<?php echo $htmlString; ?>"; //Make sure there's double 
                                                   //quotes around your php
      alert(htmlString);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Make sure you have PHP and JS in a file called .php. If its an external .js file, php inside it will not work (you can rename the JS file to a .php extension if you have it set up that way)

Also make sure you have the html, php and js setup the way above. There has to be double quotes around php, for example:

```
var userIDnum = <?php echo json_encode($userIDnum); ?>;
```

**change this to below:**

```
var userIDnum = "<?php echo json_encode($userIDnum); ?>";
```

Comment: `json_encode` already returns valid JavaScript, so there is no need to put quotes around the output. It even works for stuff that is not strictly JSON such as strings or numbers.

Comment: if its a number you don't need strings, if its a string you will need quotes around it. my biggest concern that it should work if js and php are in a .php file because php wouldn't get executed in a .js file

Comment: `json_encode` will already quote strings. If you put quotes around the output, you’ll end up with `var userIDnum = ""123""`, which is not valid JS.

Comment: whatever the case is, json_encode is breaking his alert() in the js. json_encode in this case is irrelevant whether it puts or doesn't put double quotes around the string, its causing issues.

Comment: I’m aware the alert does not work but it is certainly not the fault of `json_encode`. Either the JS is in an external file that does not get picked up by the PHP engine (e.g. because it has the wrong extension) or it’s not properly linked. One look into the browser console will yield the cause, I’m sure.